# how to use invoke command with sql server smo object

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I am trying to use invoke command to connect to a database server to backup the databases but it fails saying failed to connect to server test.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo") | Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum") | Out-Null

$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "test"
```

it works fine when i run it from local as

```
$server = New-Object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") "(local)"
```

I am using this invoke command

```
invoke-command -computername test {&("c:\backup.ps1")}
```

Comment: Why not use the -filepath parameter to invoke-command. have you set up powershell remoting on the 'test' server? you need to log on to the remote server and in powershell run `winrm quickconfig` to enable remote connections. depending on your environment you may need to do more...

Comment: there is some strange thing taking place. I have  6 scripts in a folder and right at the top is the script which runs the rest of the script, when it reaches database backup script i get "failed to connect error" but if i run it individually it works fine. because my main script is run with invoke command so i believe there is no issue with remoting

Comment: I am running main script from local machine using invokde command which works fine, but on database script i get error, when i login to remote server and run DB script on that server than it works fine

Comment: Is the db server remote from the remote host? This could be the 'double hop problem'. Google that for more information, but you will probably have to change your winrm configuration to enable kerberos, or else run the database scripts from a local session

Comment: We worked around a problem similar to this by encrypting the credentials and explicitly re authenticating in the remote session.

Comment: yes there was authetication issue, when i declared the credentials , it worked for me